# I have “CMS” made by myself with PHP and I cannot make my websites appear on google

Tags: php, cms

I have developed an Admin Panel that you can use to change conents on the website.

It works basically like this:

You use functions to generate HTML like menus, footers, side modules, etc. 
I use classes to load the content from MySQL
The back end is just some administrative pages that shows you an WYSIWYG editor and that's what you save as content and that's what is is going to appear in the website.

I have functions like this in the HTML generator:

```
public static function renderHead(
        $title = "", 
        $keywords = META_KEYWORDS, 
        $description = META_DESCRIPTION, 
        $css = array(), 
        $scripts = array()
        ) {
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/fancybox.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/nivo-themes/nivo-slider.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/nivo-themes/default/default.css"/>
        <?php 
        foreach($css as $var) {
            ?>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $var; ?>"/>
            <?php
        }
        foreach($scripts as $var) {
            ?>
            <script src="<?php echo $var; ?>"></script>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $keywords; ?>"/>
        <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>"/>
    </head>
    <body class="public">
    <?php
}
```

In the administration panel you can decide which keywords are you gonna use and stuff like that... when I see a website online I see source code with all the Keywords, Description, Titles and so... but my websites has been online for months and they just do not appear on Google :( not even if I put "theaddress.com" in the google search bar!

It's driving me crazy.

IMPORTANT:

You can see an example Here http://chicagos.co
This website has all the keywords and stuff like that, but it does not appear on google even if you type the domain, check the source code.

I know that it shows "thedomain.com/views/thepage.php" and I want to know how can I use HTAccess to remove the Views folder from the URL, because I made the admin panel using MVC practice.

Any help from people that knows about SEO and stuff will be very very helpfull. Thanks, let me know if you need more information.

Comment: The site looks good! The source looks okay though I only perused it quickly. The only thing I see with a quick glance is that it is non-English. Which Google site are you looking to rank in?

Comment: On Google.com.co for Colombia. I want to know besides the HTML headers what else can I do so it actually appears on Google. Thanks for replying

Comment: I would suggest a couple of things. Use schema.org to markup your address, phone number, etc. Perhaps Thing > Organization > LocalBusiness > FoodEstablishment > Restaurant. There may be better options so look around a bit. I would also create a Google Webmaster Tools account and link it to your site and validate it. Also consider Google Places. It can take a long while for a site to be discovered. It helps to tell Google about your site and using markup may help to get into the right Google. It may still take a while. Other than that, I will have to think longer and harder.

Comment: Well spotted w3d!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You can see an example Here `http://chicagos.co` This website has all the keywords and stuff like that, but it does not appear on google even if you type the domain, check the source code.

`chicagos.co` doesn't appear in the SERPs because you are redirecting it to another domain!?

- `chicagos.co` does a 301 redirect to `chicagospizza.co`
- `chicagospizza.co` then does a 302 redirect to `chicagos.com.co`!?

And `chicagos.com.co` **is indexed by Google**. You cannot expect `chicagos.co` to appear in the SERPs if you are redirecting to another domain! Why so many redirects?

(You've also got script after the closing BODY tag which is dubious.)

Comment: Nice catch! I looked and missed the redirect entirely. Excellent.

Comment: Yup, completely missed the redirects, that would do it!

Comment: Oh wow, that's why... then the proper method is simple. If I have a website and two or more domains, what I have to do is to create addon domains in the Hosting Account, then, not redirect via HTML o HTACCESS but use the same folder and set up the DNS. Is that right?

Comment: Well, yes and no... Yes, setting these additional domains as "add-on" (or "parked") domains will potentially allow you to access your site via any of these domains. HOWEVER, if you have the same content accessible via different URLs (ie. different domains) then you potentially have "duplicate content" issues. Why do you have multiple domains? If this is an attempt at SEO, to boost your ranking, then think again. For SEO (and your users), you should probably be redirecting to a single domain, as you are doing already - but redirect to the one you want indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't index or not index a site based on how the site is generated. There is nothing wrong with the code on your site, Google just hasn't found it yet. There are somethings you can do to help -

1. Sign up for Google Analytics and add the tracking code to your site. You should do this anyway as the information is critical to the success of the site and it's free.
2. Sign up for Google Webmaster tools, connect it to your Analytics you created in #1
3. Create a sitemap.xml file and submit it through Webmaster tools (http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html)
4. Get a Google+ account using the Google account you used in #1. Create a business page for the business, make sure to fill out all the info.
5. Go to Google places and either claim or submit the business - https://www.google.com/business/placesforbusiness/
6. Submit the website to any local directories that accept business listings.

Once you get through these basic steps, you should have the site listed pretty quickly.

Comment: Unless the domain you want indexed is being redirected!

Comment: That's correct Brent Firar, I'm gonna fix that... I'm gonna set up DNS with a single folder instead of redirecting.